# как POST и GET изменяют url

Tags: post, url, get

Здравствуйте, 
Было дано задание по определенной ссылке. В ссылке есть следующие данные (на данный момент она не рабочая, я ее как пример обозначила):

```
http://somehost/?token=1
```

Далее говорится условие, можно посмотреть задания с помощью get [exercise/num] метода в url

Где я применила след. логику

```
http://somehost/exercise/1?token=1

http://somehost/exercise/2?token=1
```

Однако сложность возникает, когда говорится, что выполнение задания можно начать, используя post [exercise/num/ready]
Я попыталась реализовать следующее:

```
http://somehost/exercise/1/ready?token=1
```

или

```
http://somehost/exercise/1?token=1&action=ready
```

Однако ничего не происходит. Страница не обновляется на другую.

Может быть я не понимаю как правильно применить метод post в данном случае.

Само задание построено только на игре с изменением url!!!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: POST через адрессную строку не делается

Comment: да, но если просят это сделать в игровом формате, возможно ли как-то это обозначить?

Comment: пост можно передать через HTML форму или непосредственно формируя заголовки и ответ сервера. Если надо просто передать несколько параметров - это можно сделать и ГЕТ-ом

Comment: согласна. но условие задания гласит иначе. необходимо передать через post

Comment: Тогда уточните вопрос. ПОСТ требует или HTML  или серверного языка (типа РНР). В вопросе показана только адрессная строка. К ней ПОСТ так просто не прикрутишь

Comment: извините, если непонятно. изменения должны происходить только в адресной строке. подсказкой является только условие: post [exercise/num/ready]. Я надеюсь, что возможно изменить строку, так как в какой-нибудь API все эти команды уже прописаны. Только они специально находятся за кадром.

Comment: ПОСТ невозомжно сделать средствами адресной строки. Точка. Если надо - делайте форму с методом ПОСТ, тогда уйдет

Comment: Не хочется с вами спорить. просто дано задание, где надо следовать написанным командам. и дана подсказка как достичь той или иной страницы. Для этого это и называется "вызовом", посколько надо следовать определенной логике, а не писать просто форму с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Метод GET отправляет скрипту всю собранную информацию формы как часть URL:
  http://somehost/exercise/1/ready?token=1

Метод POST передает данные таким образом, что пользователь сайта уже не видит передаваемые скрипту данные:
  http://somehost/exercise/1/ready

Comment: А если в самом задании нужно будет передать никнейм участника. и задание выглядит как post [name/nickname]. значит что в данных установленных правилах, можно передавать и параметры. на сколько я понимаю, post отравляет данные. а моя задача отправить то, что я `ready` начать. п.с. к сожалению, такой вариант тоже пробора, но он не работает

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось решить этот вопрос.
Я открыла веб консоль, затем в графе network поменяла мануальной ссылку на ту, которую предлагала в самом начале. И далее сменила сама GET на POST.
Спасибо за советы и комментарии!

Comment: многие инструменты и фреймвоки позволяют эмитировать post-запрос в виде get-запроса. т.е. параметры отображаются после '?' в url, но вы должны понимать, что в реальности параметры передаются в заголовке

Comment: Да. спасибо за уточнение